# com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Guice creation errors

Tags: presto

I got the following error when trying to start presto server, how can I diagnose what property is malformed or something else? Thanks.

config file:

```
coordinator=true
datasources=jmx
http-server.http.port=8080
presto-metastore.db.type=h2
presto-metastore.db.filename=var/db/MetaStore
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
```

exception is

2013-11-11T11:11:39.582-0800    ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Guice creation errors:

1) Error: Constraint violation with property prefix '': environment is malformed (for class io.airlift.node.NodeConfig)
  at io.airlift.node.NodeModule.configure(NodeModule.java:34)

1 error
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Error: Constraint violation with property prefix '': environment is malformed (for class io.airlift.node.NodeConfig)
  at io.airlift.node.NodeModule.configure(NodeModule.java:34)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:154) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:277) ~[bootstrap-0.84.jar:0.84]
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:137) ~[presto-server-0.52.jar:0.52]
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:50) ~[presto-server-0.52.jar:0.52]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies for the very unfriendly and unhelpful error message. This is on our list of things to fix.

The error "environment is malformed" means that the `node.environment` property (in the `node.properties` file) is set but fails to match the following regular expression: `[a-z0-9][_a-z0-9]*`. In other words, it must be lowercase, start with an alphanumeric character, and have only alphanumeric or underscores in subsequent characters.

Try a simpler name like `test` or `production`.

Comment: That's it. I had "-" in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it's of consolation, but I am getting something similar on Centos:

> 1) Error: Constraint violation with property prefix '': environment
>   may not be null (for class io.airlift.node.NodeConfig)   at
>   io.airlift.node.NodeModule.configure(NodeModule.java:34)
>
> 1 error com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

Comment: This means that the `node.environment` property is not set. Please see the "Node Properties" section in the deployment instructions: http://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html